# select costume column by position pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with number of columns. I need to select some columns by their position. for example, I want to select columns 0,3,6,7,15 (by position) from the dataset. I tried using iloc but it seems it is applicable in the range of position, ( I may be wrong?) If there are any better ideas?

Comment: Use a list of indices `df.iloc[:,[0,3,6,7,15]]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to use `iloc`, you can try:

```
pos_list = [0, 3, 6, 7, 15]
df = df[df.columns[pos_list]]
```

If this `pos_list` is not the indices you want, you can try to find the indices in `df.columns` by using it like a list.

Answer (score -1):

Use this syntax: `data.iloc[:, [0,1,20,22]]`

Where 0,1,20 and 22 is the column index.

Comment: I used the same method but, in the result, I get data from column position 1 which I don't indicate and don't want to be here. Here is my syntax: dataset=data.iloc[:, [0,4,8,..]] dataset 
0 tcp private REJ 0 0  </br>
0 tcp private REJ 0 0 
output
 0 tcp 0 0 0 0.06 21 </br>
0 tcp 0 0 0 0.06 21
 I don't know why data from column( having tcp, icmp), position 1 appeared here.